# jQuery String selector add string from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a line that creates a simple box like so:

```
var box = $('<button>').addClass('box');
```

With using the css:

```
.box {
    border-radius: 0.7vw;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 50vw;
    margin: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #d87c2d;
}
```

All fine, I get those boxes, I can even click on them.

But what I really need is generating some usable elements.

For that, I usually like to keep components separate (hope I use the correct terminology), so I made a text file with the following content:

```
<div>
    <div class="tile" id="eventName"> Event name</div><br/>
    <div class="tile" id="eventDate">2017.01.01. </div>
    <div class="tile" id="eventTime">12.00</div><br/> 
    <div class="tile" id="description">Some boring example description about the meaningless </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to put this inside the `$(-here-)` instead of the simple `<button>` I have there.

To get that I tried

```
var box = $('/html/tileInside').addClass('box');
```

but didn't work, I believe JS thinks I want just the `string` */html/tileInside* there which obviously doesn't mean anything.

So is there a way to add a `string` from a txt file inside the jQuery string selector?

Comment: there is no way jquery would know it is a string that somehow references some random file.... My guess is you want .load(), but I doubt that is what you really want....

Comment: Just FYI the HTML you're trying to create is invalid. You cannot place a `div` within a `button`. Having a `script` in there isn't a great idea either - especially ones which repeatedly include the same JS files.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. So after correcting the html, shall I just try to read the txt's content to a variable and put that inside? Or mess around with `innerHTML`?

Comment: As said, you cannot access a random file with javascript that simple. Consider using ajax `$('<button>').load('/html/tileInside');` ...and yes, button as wrapper for script is kinda bad.

Comment: @sofl Thanks, it works. Do you want to convert that to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ajax here.

```
$('<div></div>').load('/html/tileInside');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It even works if I use `.html` instead of a `.txt`. Great hint, thanks again.